# Geckodriver broke run processes for Firefox, Snap store and Pycharm Community on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: firefox, 23.10, mozilla

After installing geckodriver with Firefox with apt alongside with Firefox from snap store I'm not able to run Firefox, Snap store and Pycharm Community. After system start when I'm trying to run any application it throws error:

```
~$ pycharm-community
pycharm-community: error: Address in use (os error 98)
WebDriver implementation for Firefox

Usage: 

Options:
      --allow-hosts <ALLOW_HOSTS>...
          List of hostnames to allow. By default the value of --host is allowed,
          and in addition if that's a well known local address, other variations
          on well known local addresses are allowed. If --allow-hosts is
          provided only exactly those hosts are allowed.
      --allow-origins <ALLOW_ORIGINS>...
          List of request origins to allow. These must be formatted as
          scheme://host:port. By default any request with an origin header is
          rejected. If --allow-origins is provided then only exactly those
          origins are allowed.
      --android-storage <ANDROID_STORAGE>
          Selects storage location to be used for test data (deprecated).
          [possible values: auto, app, internal, sdcard]
  -b, --binary <BINARY>
          Path to the Firefox binary
      --connect-existing
          Connect to an existing Firefox instance
  -h, --help
          Prints this message
      --host <HOST>
          Host IP to use for WebDriver server [default: 127.0.0.1]
      --jsdebugger
          Attach browser toolbox debugger for Firefox
      --log <LEVEL>
          Set Gecko log level [possible values: fatal, error, warn, info,
          config, debug, trace]
      --log-no-truncate
          Disable truncation of long log lines
      --marionette-host <HOST>
          Host to use to connect to Gecko [default: 127.0.0.1]
      --marionette-port <PORT>
          Port to use to connect to Gecko [default: system-allocated port]
  -p, --port <PORT>
          Port to use for WebDriver server [default: 4444]
      --profile-root <PROFILE_ROOT>
          Directory in which to create profiles. Defaults to the system
          temporary directory.
  -v...
          Log level verbosity (-v for debug and -vv for trace level)
  -V, --version
          Prints version and copying information
      --websocket-port <PORT>
          Port to use to connect to WebDriver BiDi [default: 9222]
```

And the error the same for Firefox or Snap store. Also if I grep geckodriver process by port 4444, kill it:

```
~$ lsof -i :4444
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pycharm-c 28317 siarhei    3u  IPv4 156787      0t0  TCP localhost:4444 (LISTEN)

~$ kill -9 28317
```

and will try to start an application, it'll stack on this:

```
~$ pycharm-community
1709564074273   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4444
```

And nothing happens after. How can I fix run for those applications?

**UPD: Tried to uninstall apt version, but it didn't help, errors the same**

**UPD: Solution was not found so OS was reinstalled.**